# Ruby method call to each using "include Enumerable"

Tags: ruby, methods, enumerable

I a trying to follow a tutorial with Ruby, but am getting very confused. Everywhere I find seems to say that defining an instance variable is done like so;

```
class Example
  def fun
    # CODE
  end
end

e = Example.new
e.fun     # <- Will run your code
```

Bu I really really don't get why this isn't working

```
class Example
  include Enumerable

  def initialise
    @members = ["a", "b"]
  end

  def each
    @members.each do |member|
      yield member
    end
  end

end
```

When I call

```
e = Example.new

e.each do |elmt|
  puts elmt
end
```

I get the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Can anybody help me figure out how to get this working. I cant find out what's wrong, below are 3 of the many sources that lead me to believe this should work. I am obviously doing something wrong, but I just cant see it

sources;
http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/ss/Using-The-Enumerable-Module.htm
http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/
Book: Engineering Software as a Service

Comment: BTW: if all your `each` method is doing is to pass on the block to another method, having the block be anonymous (which is supposed to reduce clutter) is actually detrimental, since if you give it a name, you can just pass it along: `def each(&blk) @members.each(&blk) end`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo. It's `initialize`, not `initialise`. Your `@members` instance var was never assigned to, that's why it's `nil`.

Comment: @LukeTurner If it were the natural English language, then your typo had been dismissed as American versus British, but Ruby is more American- than British-oriented.

Comment: Thanks, that's had me going for ages.